# Futuristic Cartoon from 80s-90s

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This one I've been chasing for over a decade now.

The story is about five young people. They don't have superpowers, but they have gadgets at their disposal. Their main ones are individual flying boards which they stand on. They are pretty big and look sci-fi. On top of that they have individual weapons.

1. The Leader - I recall him having blonde hair. When in costume he seemed to be of blueish color.

   Weapon - I think he had a sword, with a big handle with maybe fire or some sort of laser coming out of it.
2. The Woman - She was white skinned, dark haired.

   Weapon - I think it was also a sword but smaller then the Leader's. And i recall that she carried it horizontally behind her waist
3. Man #2 - He was a big black guy, kinda like the Strongman of the team. Can't recall what his weapon was though.
4. Man #3 - Skinny white guy. He had longer hair and his costume was purple.

   Weapon - He had a big boomerang that he carried on his back.
5. Man #4 - Another white guy. In his costume he looked sort of like a cowboy. I think he was wearing dark pants, red vest, some type of white hat, glasses and a ponytail.

   Weapon - He had two guns on his belt that shot ropes.

Their enemy was some sort of evil cyborg/robot. As far as I can remember, he was created by Leader's father but he went rogue. For some reason he had an adopted daughter that was human. I think her and the Leader had some sort of romantic chemistry going on. He also had different minions at his disposal. They were some combination of humanoid mutants/cyborgs and they all had different powers.

It was definitely oriented for more mature teenagers rather then kids. It used to run on some channel when I was a kid. It was in Russian so I can't be 100% sure it was originally in English. However, from what I can recall everything about its style pointed to being American.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware: if one of the answers is correct, it can be "accepted" by clicking the check next to it. If none are correct, let us know where they don't match up or update the question if you've remembered any other details.

Answer (score 40):

[Skysurfer Strike Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skysurfer_Strike_Force) aired from 1995 to 1996 with reruns from 1999 to 2000. Based on your description, you've remembered this with amazing accuracy.

The main characters, the Skysurfers are a very close match. They [fly around on boards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr948.jpg) and their nemesis, Cybron, looks very cybernetic in [this trailer](https://vimeo.com/ondemand/skysurferstrikeforce/262264203?autoplay=1).

- Jack Hollister(Skysurfer One) is the leader, a blond dude with a beam saber.
- Micky Flannigan(Crazy Stunts) dual wields pistols that can also shoot
  out wires.
- Kimberley Sakai(Sliced Ice) is a dark haired woman with a sword.
- Nathan James(Air Enforcer) is a beefy black guy that's a heavy weapons specialist.
- Brad Wright(Soar Loser) has boomerangs, including a big one on his
  back.

[image: Skysurfer Strike Force Team]

Comment: For those that ask, I had no secret to find this. I just went through a list of every '90s cartoon [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animated_television_series_of_the_1990s) looking for promising titles to do images searches on them.

Comment: I wonder if the show ever tried to explain how Wright got saddled with the codename "Soar Loser."

Comment: @notovny I've no idea, but when I first came across [this image](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-VViopCVLuN4/ULN03uyrWFI/AAAAAAAAABc/6RXeKL_RKMI/s1600/animated-tv-series-1.2-800X800.jpg) before looking at the Wikipedia article I thought, "Haha! Someone's made up ridiculous names for the characters." Then I found out those were the real names.

Answer (score 9):

A team of 5 people (in the standard formation composed of young leader, dark-haired one, fat one, kid and woman; see also the ["Five-Man Band" trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FiveManBand)) is a staple of many anime, so more details could be needed to find the correct series.

However, this could be [*"Science Ninja Team Gatchaman"* (*Kagaku Ninja Tai Gatchaman*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Ninja_Team_Gatchaman). The first American adaptation (with cuts, edits, name changes and additions) was produced in 1978 and was titled [*"Battle of the Planets"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Planets); a second, more faithful adaptation titled [*"G-Force: Guardians of Space"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Force:_Guardians_of_Space#Team_variations_across_different_versions) was made in 1986.

[image: the five main characters]

Matching elements:

- while it originally aired in Japan from 1972 to 1974, both the first American adaptation and the second one are near or inside the requested time interval (eighties - nineties); moreover, in the following years these adaptations were in turn used as sources to produce localizations in other countries
- **Ken the Eagle**, the leader of the group, wields some kind of laser sword

[image: Ken the Eagle with his sword]

- **Joe the Condor** uses guns

[image: Joe the Condor with a gun]

Non-matching elements:

- **Jun the Swan** (the girl) uses a weaponized yo-yo (as far as the images I found show) and not a sword
- I couldn't find images of someone using a giant boomerang
- Ken does not have blond hair
- no one matches the "big black guy" description
- they don't seem to use flying boards

<sub>Many thanks to [@BoogaRoo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/52902/booga-roo) for pointing out some important non-matching elements. Having read [his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237192/40711), I'm personally convinced that he found the correct title.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

[Monster Force (1994)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Force)

Blonde leader wearing blue uniform: check

White skinned dark red haired woman: check

Big black guy: check

Guy wearing a cowboy poncho: check

Evil cyborg guy: check

See if this looks familiar: