# 80s/90s cartoon about scifi mountaneers

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Inspired by [this thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237172/futuristic-cartoon-from-80s-90s) - I remember watching a cartoon in my childhood (mid 90s)about a group of people who battled some baddies (I think) in a very mountainous terrain. Their main gimmick was backpacks that could shoot harpoons simultaneously to the front and rear, stretching a rope across the mountains that they would then slide down on. Maybe they also had motors in the backpacks which allowed them to climb upwards on these ropes? Not sure. The cartoon was aired on Cartoon Network, but that's all I can remember about it. It was shown fairly rarely and I only saw a few episodes ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Sky Commanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Commanders)*.

There was a lot of mountaineering and backpacks and grappling hooks (and [merch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsJ0EAHm2XA&ab_channel=ToyGalaxy)).

.

Comment: Yes! You're too fast, I still need to wait for 5 minutes before I can accept your answer! :D

Comment: [Happy to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)